# Отображение изменений в JTable в цикле

Tags: update, jtable

При выполнении данного кода, данные в таблице изменяются только после окончания цикла по k, т.е. вместо 0,1,2,3,4 в соотвествующих ячейках (5 столбец) три раза я получаю эти данные, но после того как закончиться while.

Код приведен для примера

```
int k = 0;
while(k < 3){
/....
Do something
.../
    for(int i=0; i < 5;i++) {                     
        model.setValueAt(i, i, 4);
        model.fireTableCellUpdated(i, 4);
        //table.updateUI();
    }                           
  k++;                      
}
```

Собственно мне нужно бесконечно выводить изменяющиеся данные на экран в табличном виде после каждой итерации с выходом из цикла по кнопке.

Столкнулся с тем что данные обновляются только после окончания цикла.

Пробовал `table.updateUI()`, `model.fireTableCellUpdated()`, паузить Thread  - не работает.

Comment: Спасибо,  
@Nicolas Chabanovsky за редактирование

Answer (score 1):

Поместил выполнение цикла в отдельный поток и все заработало.

```
Thread worker = new Thread(){
  public void run(){
    ArrayList<Request> requests = buildRequests(); // forming requests
    //__________отображение данных в цикле   
    int k=0;
    while(k < 5){
      ParseTable work = new ParseTable(requests);
      ArrayList<String> answer = work.getOut();
      for(int i=0; i < answer.size();i++) {                     
      model.setValueAt(answer.get(i), i, 4);                                 model.fireTableCellUpdated(i, 4);                          
    }
      try {Thread.sleep(100); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {};
      k++;                      
   }
   //_______________отображение данных в цикле 
   }    
};      

worker.start();
```